# Why are my Ember.ArrayController itemControllers undefined?

Tags: ember.js

Was working before I started renaming a few things, specifically the ArrayController itself. 

 Here's my code:

```js
// list_missions.js
Create.ListMissionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'listMissionsItem',
});

// list_mission.js
Create.ListMissionsItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['listMissions'],
});
```

```html
{{#each mission in controllers.listMissions
  itemViewClass="Create.ListMissionsItemView"}}
  <div>{{mission.name}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Perhaps it's because of the way I'm setting the content with a filter? 
Like this in the route:

```js
    var missions = Breadcrumb.Mission.query({
      list: model.get('id'), range_size: 150});
    var missionsFilter = Breadcrumb.Mission.filter(
      function(m) { return m.get('list') === model; });
    this.controllerFor('listMissions').set('content', missionsFilter);
```

Should work right? But upon inspection the listMissions._subControllers are all undefined :(

 What could cause the itemController not to register properly?

Comment: Any chance you can put together a JSBin?  It sounds like you're trying to do things not in "The Ember Way (TM)" and I'm not quite sure what you're doing.

Comment: @Jeremy - It's part of a much larger code base.  Basically I'm just trying to work with a list of missions using an ArrayController.  I've reset to my last commit and it's working again.  Somewhere in my attempt to rename the ArrayController I messed something up, because so much other code uses it.  I'm attempting the rename again more carefully...

Comment: @Jeremy - You are partially right about not doing things in the Ember way.  Our application route for a listMission is actually a detail view on the mission.  Simultaneously the user can also see and work with lists of missions in another pane, with it's own controllers and views. This does go against the ember mantra of having the url be the source of truth for app state, but we are looking into the new url query params to relect the state of the other panes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I have a route with the same name:

```
Create.ListMissionsRoute = Breadcrumb.Route.extend({ ...
```

which is for a different view that does not have an explicit controller because it is an intermediate route that is never visited on its own. Hence why I didn't catch it during Find and Replace.  Duh, simple mistake.